# Android Custom URL Scheme for different apps

Tags: android, url-scheme

I would like to create a series of apps that will be opened via URL scheme. What I would like to do is to use the same base scheme for all of them but be able to specify which app to open... somthing like this:

- myApp://open?appUrl="app1" -> open first app
- myApp://open?appUrl="app2" -> open second app
- etc...

Is it possible?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `<intent-filter>` in your `<activity>`:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.Activity">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="myApp" />
     <data android:host="app1" />
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

this should work for `myApp://app1`, I am not sure if intent-filter can parse more complicated URLs like `open?appUrl="app1"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You'll need to specify the URL scheme within the corresponding [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) of your apps.